# Is it normal for IBM Connections opensocial gadgets to make 2 HTTP requests on gadgets.io.makeRequest?

Tags: opensocial, ibm-connections

Within an IBM Connections sharebox/share dialog gadget `my-sharebox.xml`, I make the following request:

`gadgets.io.makeRequest(url, function (response) { ... });`

Using `tcpflow` on the IBM Connections server to capture the outgoing request & response, I see **2 HTTP requests**.

The first one to the `url` specified above, and a second request to the gadget XML file, `my-sharebox.xml`.

- Is this second request expected behaviour?
- Is it possible to somehow suppress the second request?

Answer (score 2):

In a production environment it should be caching the gadget XML and only fetch it once.  That will usually happen when the gadget is rendered.  Do you have all debug parameters  related to opensocial disabled?

Comment: Hi Ryan, yes, you guessed I'm in developer mode. Which debug parameters do you mean? And where?  Thanks Ryan :)